# I want to put a border on the left, bottom, and right of my iframe, but it is not working

Tags: html, css, iframe, border

I want a border to be on the left, bottom, and right of my iframe, but that is not happening. On a big computer screen, I get the left and bottom border, but on my small computer, I just get the left border. The problem is with the main index file. The borders are coloured in blue and the background of the page is coloured in yellow. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?
Here is the link:
https://replit.com/@RahikAhsan/Multi-Ware#index.html
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "Iframe/Resource/DTD/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Multi-Ware</title>
  <link href="Iframe/Resource/Style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="Iframe/Resource/Script/971e3befae.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="Iframe/Resoruce/Script/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
<!-- ios support -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="Iframe/Resource/Image/Icon.png" />

 
  <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Iframe/Resource/Image/favicon.ico">
  <style type="text/css">
    #Close-Button {border: 1px solid black; background-color: #d4d0c7; color: black; text-decoration: none; font-size: 18px;}
    #Close-Button:hover {color: #ffffff; background-color: #ff030b;}
    #Close-Button:visited {color: black;}
    html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;}
  </style>
</head>
<!-- change bgcolor to #0b2370 after you are done working with the frame -->
<body bgcolor="yellow">
  <font face="monospace" color="white">
    <b><font size="+2"><img src="Iframe/Resource/Image/Icon.png" style="height: 19.3125px; width: 17.3125px; padding-left: 5px; padding-top: 5px;"> Multi-Ware</font></b> <span style="float: right;"> <button onclick="toggleFullScreen()" title="Full-Screen/Exit Full-Screen Mode" id="fullScreenExitFullScreenButton"> <i class="fa-solid fa-expand"></i> </button> <a href="#" onclick="Javascript: top.close();" id="Close-Button" title="Close"> X </a> </span>
    <br />
    <iframe frameborder="0" style="/* position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; */ width:209vh; height:96%; border-left:5px solid #0b2370; border-bottom:5px solid #0b2370; border-right:5px solid #0b2370; /* margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; */ z-index:999998;" src="Iframe/Home.html" name="Main-Iframe"></iframe>
    <div id="contextMenu" class="context-menu" style="display: none; z-index: 999999;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Iframe/Help/Help.html" class="Drop-Down-Menu-Link" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="Iframe/About.html" class="Drop-Down-Menu-Link" target="Main-Iframe">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="Iframe/Share.html" class="Drop-Down-Menu-Link" target="Main-Iframe">Share</a></li>
        <li><a href="Iframe/Feedback.html" class="Drop-Down-Menu-Link" target="Main-Iframe">Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="Javascript: top.close();" class="Drop-Down-Menu-Link">Close</a></li>
        
    </ul>
    </div>
  </font>
  

  
  
  
  <script src="Iframe/Resource/Script/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register("/serviceWorker.js")
      .then(res => console.log("service worker registered"))
      .catch(err => console.log("service worker not registered", err))
  })
}
function toggleFullScreen() {
  if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||
   (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
      document.cancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
      document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
  }
}

  </script>
  
  
</body>
  

</html>
```

Thank you.

I was editing the code, changing percentage to vh, reducing the percentage, etc.

Comment: sometimes working with CSS  you have to use the !important rule, it will override ALL previous styling rules for that specific property on that element!  eg. {border-bottom: 10px !important}. hope this works for you.

Comment: @BaburShahSayer I added the !important rule to the iframe and it still did not work:

Comment: <iframe frameborder="0" style="/* position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; */ width:209vh; height:96%; border-left:5px solid #0b2370 !important; border-bottom:5px solid #0b2370 !important; border-right:5px solid #0b2370 !important; /* margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; */ z-index:999998;" src="Iframe/Home.html" name="Main-Iframe"></iframe>